# Simple C++: How to globalise variables in C++

Tags: c++

I have an error when I try to build my program reading:
'error: 'celsius()' was not declared in this scope'

Now, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the problem is that because the function 'fahrenheit'  comes before my other function 'celsius' when I call it in the fahrenheit function, it won't work. Now, it would be simple enough to switch them around but fahrenheit is also called in the celsius function.

In python, all you need to do is just globalise it with the 'global' syntax so what is the C++ equivalent?

Thanks

PS. Here is my code if you want it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int fahrenheit(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\nYOU HAVE CHOSEN FAHRENHEIT TO CELSIUS MODE";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------------------";
    bool again;
    again = true;
    while (again == true){
    int tempurf;
    cout << "\nFahrenheit Temperature to be Converted: ";
    cin >> tempurf;
    int tempurc;
    tempurc = tempurf - 32;
    tempurc = tempurc * 5;
    tempurc = tempurc / 9;
    cout << "\n\n" << tempurf << " F is " << tempurc << " C";
    cout << "\n\n\n\nWHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO: ";
    cout << "\n      - ANOTHER CONVERSION TYPE A";
    cout << "\n      - FOR CELSIUS MODE TYPE C";
    cout << "\n      - TO EXIT TYPE E";
    bool goodc;
    goodc = false;
    while (goodc == false){
    string choosing;
    cout << "\n ";
    cin >> choosing;
    if (choosing == "A" or choosing == "a"){
        system("CLS");
        goodc = true;
    }
    else if (choosing == "C" or choosing == "c"){
        goodc = true;
        again = false;
        celsius();
    }
    else if (choosing == "E" or choosing == "e"){
        goodc = true;
        again = false;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "\n Invalid Choice";
    }
    }
    }
}

int celsius(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "---------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\nYOU HAVE CHOSEN CELSIUS TO FAHRENHEIT MODE";
    cout << "\n---------------------------------------------";
    bool again;
    again = true;
    while (again == true){
    int tempuc;
    cout << "\nCelsius Temperature to be Converted: ";
    cin >> tempuc;
    int tempuf;
    tempuf = tempuc * 9;
    tempuf = tempuf / 5;
    tempuf = tempuf + 32;
    cout << "\n\n" << tempuc << " C is " << tempuf << " F";
    cout << "\n\n\n\nWHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO: ";
    cout << "\n      - ANOTHER CONVERSION TYPE A";
    cout << "\n      - FOR FAHRENHEIT MODE TYPE F";
    cout << "\n      - TO EXIT TYPE E";
    bool goodc;
    goodc = false;
    while (goodc == false){
    string choosing;
    cout << "\n ";
    cin >> choosing;
    if (choosing == "A" or choosing == "a"){
        system("CLS");
        goodc = true;
    }
    else if (choosing == "F" or choosing == "f"){
        goodc = true;
        again = false;
        fahrenheit();
    }
    else if (choosing == "E" or choosing == "e"){
        goodc = true;
        again = false;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "\n Invalid Choice";
    }
    }
    }
}


int main(){
    cout << "Welcome to the Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter!";
    cout << "\n By Ben Sarachi";
    cout << "\n\nWhich way would you like to convert to:";
    cout << "\n      - If you would like Fahrenheit to Celsius please type F";
    cout << "\n      - If you would like Celsius to Fahrenheit please type C";
    // GC stands for good choice
    bool gc;
    gc = false;
    while (gc == false){
    string choice;
    cout << "\n   ";
    cin >> choice;
    //Call Functions
    if (choice == "F" or choice == "f"){
        gc = true;
        fahrenheit();
    }
    else if (choice == "C" or choice == "c"){
         gc = true;
         celsius();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid Choice";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is an acceptable question, but too much code. Try to show only SSCCE.

Comment: You're going to want to check out your comparisons on the if statements and look how to actually compare a string something like: choosing.compare("A") == 0 
Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: Oh ok, I will do next time. I just wanted you guys to see what I meant.

Comment: TO EVERYONE WHO HAS ANSWERED, THANK YOU, I CAN'T UPVOTE THOUGH AS MY REPUTATION IS AT A GRAND TOTAL OF 4. BUT THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR ANSWERS I REALLY APPRECIATE IT.

Comment: It means if choosing (which is the variable that their choice is written to) equals A (which is the one of the options, the one that lets them do another conversion) do the stuff in the {}

Answer (score 4):

You want to add a forward declaration for your function so that the compiler knows the function exists. What's happening is that Fahrenheit is calling Celsius, but the compiler doesn't know what Celsius is at that point.

At the top of your code, add the following just below your includes:

```
int fahrenheit();
int celsius();
```

This tells the compiler that you will be defining those functions at some point.

Then you can declare your functions in any order in the file that you like.

Also, for future reference, that forward declaration should have the same *signature* as your function. So if you had a function like:

```
void foo(int bar) { ... }
```

then your forward declaration would be:

```
void foo(int);
```

Comment: Should I do it for Fahrenheit? Is that just good c++ coding because the first thing I do after the                       'using namespace std;'                                                      Is define fahrenheit

Comment: Its not technically necessary since Fahrenheit is the first thing you're defining. However, I tend to put the main function at the top of the file since it's the starting point, so I end up putting forward declarations for any functions within that file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is function forward declarations. Put the following string before definition of `fahrenheit` function:

```
int celsius();
```

This will tell the compiler, that such a function exists and has the following prototype. But the body will be introduce at some point later.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just started c++ so I am a bit of a noob... Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because at the time of compiling the `fahrenheit()` function, `celsius()` is not known. You have to forward declare it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int celsius(); // this is the forward declaration

int fahrenheit(){

  // do something
  celsius();
}

int celsius(){
  // implement the function
}
```

The alternative is you create a class and put the two functions as member of that class. You won't need forward declaration then (though declaring a class is arguably another form of that).

You have several other problems in your code:

- your functions are set to return int, but not all paths return a value
- what is `or` here `choice == "F" or choice == "f"`? is it #defined somewhere as `||`?
- do not use conditions such as `gc == false` or `gc == true`. prefer to use `gc` and `!gc` as in `if(gc)` or `while(!gc)`

Comment: `or` is defined in the C++ standard: en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: I know that there are different ways of defining a function (int, char, float, double, void, bool) but I didn't really know what to use... I used int and it worked (it's the same story with the gc == false) but what would you recommend for my situation?

Comment: If a function does not return a value, then the return type must be `void`. If it returns anything else than void, then all the execution paths in the function must return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Separate function **declaration** from **definition**.
Change your code to something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int celsius();
int fahrenheit();


int fahrenheit()
{
    // ...
}

int celsius()
{
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't works. Also I've not included `std::string` class. In my answer I've added include statement(2nd line)

Comment: There are alternative operators like `or`, `and`, `not` and so on in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative